# rspec failing for user spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I am using factorybot with ruby 2.5.5 version
spec fails with following error

```
 Failure/Error: @user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
      NoMethodError:
        undefined method `password=' for #<User:0x000055dcec0bc628>
      # /bundle/gems/carrierwave-crop-0.1.2/lib/carrierwave/crop/model_additions.rb:42:in `method_missing'
```

//factory bot code

```
 FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user, aliases: [:author] do
    fullname { 'user1' }
    email { "user#{rand(999)}@gmail.com" }
    password { 'passwordis12345' }
  end
end
```

Comment: What does your user model look like? Is there a field `password` you can set?

Comment: oh, I found the answer it was because of missing attr_accessor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of missing `attr_accessor`